# Testing a jquery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

Hi all I am new to jquery and javascript.I have written a code and want to test it.But I am stuck at some point and need help from experts.

Here is my jquery class define in **myfile.js**

```
$.fn.MyClass = function(arg1 ,arg2, arg3) {

  function MyFirstFunc (arg1, arg3) {
     //Do some thing 
     return arg1 + arg3;

  };

  function MySecFunc (arg2, arg3) {
     //Do some thing 

  };
MyFirstFunc(arf1 ,arg2);
}
```

And in my index.html file I have to call my jquery class on DOM object like this

```
$("#div1").MyClass(agr1_val, arg2_val, arg3_val);
```

Now I want to do unit testing of these functions and keep the test cases in a separate file.I have chose Qunit.
I have wrote following test

```
test('MyFirstFunction function test', function() {
    equal(MyFirstFunc (4, 5),"9" ,"function working correctly");
});
```

Also in my index_test.html file  I have given the path of myfile.js but still Qunit is giving me error

**Died on test #1     at file:///var/www/test.js:2:1: MyFirstFunc is not defined**

Can any one kindly guide me where I am doing wrong and how to test functions by keeping the test cases in a separate file
Or any other better way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all your are declaring bad methods in your jquery object.

Instead of:

```
function MyFirstFunc (arg1, arg3) {
```

You should use: `this.MyFirstFunc = function(arg1, arg3) {`

Also you should call your methods with a jQuery object as in this example:

```
equal($("#div1").MyClass(1, 2, 3).MyFirstFunc(4, 5),"9" ,"function working correctly");
```

Here is an example of a working Qunit test:

```
$.fn.MyClass = function(arg1 ,arg2, arg3) {

    this.MyFirstFunc = function(arg1, arg3) {
        //Do some thing 
        return arg1 + arg3;

    };

    this.MySecFunc = function(arg2, arg3) {
        //Do some thing 
    };

  return this.MyFirstFunc(arg1, arg3);
};

$(function() {
    $("#div1").MyClass(1, 2, 3);
});

test('MyClass function test', function() {
    equal($("#div1").MyClass (1,2,3),"4" ,"function working correctly");
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your response but I want to call an init function define in my file automatically please see the edit

Comment: What do you use jquery object for then?

Comment: Actually I call this class on my DIV object and plot a graph on that div.The real code is very long so I have given a simplified example

Comment: I have edited my answer, so that it returns the result of myfirstfunc once you call MyClass. If that's not what you meant, then I am simply missing a point here :)

Comment: thanks I will check this out.Also can you tell me why have you written the last line 
test('MyClass function test', function() {
    equal($("#div1").MyClass (1,2,3),"4" ,"function working correctly");
}); As I want ot add test in separate file

Answer (score 0):

The MyFirstFunc method is not defined. MyFirstFunc and MySecFunc must be defined in the return array in order to publicly use those functions. You can define it like so

```
$.fn.MyClass = function (arg1, arg2, arg3) {

    function MyFirstFunc(arg1, arg3) {
        //Do some thing 
        return arg1 + arg3;

    };

    function MySecFunc(arg2, arg3) {
        //Do some thing 

    };

    return {
        MyFirstFunc: function (arg1, arg3) {
            return MyFirstFunc(arg1, arg3);
        },
        MySecFunc: function (arg2, arg3) {
            return MySecFunc(arg2, arg3);
        }
    }
}
```

And test it with

```
test('MyFirstFunction function test', function() {
    equal($().MyClass().MyFirstFunc(4, 5),"9" ,"function working correctly");
});
```

Comment: thanks alot for your response But I dont know why I am still getting the same error :/

Comment: I got following error now Object [object Object] has no method 'MyClass'

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with your test case, it's with your function definitions. You can't simply declare a function inside another function and expect to access it in the global namespace. A fundamental property of function definitions in JavaScript is that they're the only things that provide scope, so when you use a function as an object the object's "instance variables" (declared inside the function) are only accessible inside that object.

If you're trying to create an object with methods, you need to assign those functions to instance variables of the object. Instance variables of an object in JavaScript are defined by assigning `this.<variable>` in the constructor function (the function you use to define the object). So to give `MyClass` two methods, you should do something like this:

```
MyClass = function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {

    this.myFirstFunc = function(arg1, arg2) {
        //Do something
    };

    this.mySecFunc = function(arg1, arg2) {
        //Do something
    };
};

var myInstance = new MyClass(x,y,z);
myInstance.myFirstFunc(a,b);
```

Note that simply giving your functions' arguments the same name as the constructor's arguments doesn't pass the arguments from the constructor to the method. Defining a function does not pass it concrete arguments, so the MyFirstFunc arg1 and arg2 are interpreted as just names of the arguments you might pass to MyFirstFunc, not instructions to pass the outer function's arguments to MyFirstFunc.

Finally, the `$.fn` property is an alias to `jquery.prototype`, so what you're doing with `$.fn.MyClass = function...` is assigning a new property to the JQuery object, essentially patching the library with your own add-on. This probably isn't how you want to define functions in general, though I don't know your use case.

Comment: Thanks @Edward for your response.Actually in my case i want to use it something like this $("#div1").MyClass(agr1_val, arg2_val, arg3_val);
So I found no way but to write it like $.fn As i am very new to all this so didnt know the best way